# How can we handle a datetime error that occurs when trying to append to a SQL table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a field in a data frame that is type 'object'. I tried to convert it to datetime using this.

```
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])
```

It gives me this error: `TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime`

I think the problem is that some of the dates show up like this: `00:00:00`

I tried to do a replace, and just use some older date that has no significance. It ran, but nothing changed:

```
df['dt'] = df['dt'].replace(['00:00:00'],'2000-01-01 00:00:00')
```

I'm basically trying to run `df.to_sql` to append the data frame to a table in PostgreSQL. How can I get this date-thing fixed?

Comment: Does `datatime` mean `datetime`?

Comment: Yes. That was a typo. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

After more and more Googling, I came up with this, and it worked fine for me.

```
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'], errors='coerce')
```